# Braintree PHP SDK cURL exception

Tags: php, api, ssl, curl, braintree

I keep getting back a `Braintree_Exception_SSLCertificate` exception when I try to generate a client token using `Braintree_ClientToken::generate()`. I've got the SDK loaded and my PHP setup seems to meet the minimum requirements for the SDK.

The versions of PHP and cURL I'm running are:

`PHP 5.5.3`

`cURL 7.32.0` with `OpenSSL/1.0.1e`. SSL is enabled in my cURL module.

I noticed Braintree is enforcing TLS 1.2 so I thought that might be the issue but I tried adding the following line to Http.php in the Braintree SDK:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
```

This should set cURL to use `TLS 1.2` but it didn't seem to help and I'm not sure how to verify that the setting even took effect.

I haven't managed to successfully place a request to Braintree's API yet so I'm worried this is something I'm doing wrong or maybe the version of cURL I'm using is no good. Is there anything I need to enable SSL that I've missed?

Thanks,
Brad.

Comment: have you found any solution to this?

Comment: No, not yet. I was going to try updating my version of curl and/or OpenSSL but haven't gotten to it yet. Probably try tonight.

Comment: Ya, I'm trying that too. Braintree has updated to tls1.0, thats why old stop working.. so have to update openssl 1.0.1 and up..

Comment: I have updated to MAMP PRO 4 (which has openssl 1.0.1^) and it is start working again now. Hope you can get it working too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/).

The cURL version that you are using may be your issue, because the libcurl version should be  greater than 7.40. I would recommend updating to this version, since TLS 1.2 support is added at that version and beyond.

Also, this [github link](https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update#php) takes you through the process that Braintree requires for your PHP integration to be up to date with TLS 1.2.  I'm mentioning this since you wanted a way to check if your cURL was being set to instantiate TLS 1.2.

The way to do this would be:
`php -r 'echo json_encode(curl_version(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);'`

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was indeed helpful. This led to a classic snowball effect where upgrading one thing required upgrading another thing (and another). In the end, I upgraded to a newer version of Ubuntu which means new PHP, new cURL, new everything. However I'm pretty confident the cURL version was the primary issue. I'm on cURL v7.47.0 now and I'm able to connect to the API and process transactions nice and smoothly. Awesome! Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have just climbed Himalaya. The solution above is not a solution at all. Here's what I did to solve this problem. For Centos 7 machine, yum update is sometimes useless. The only solution is to update OpenSSL and Curl manually.

There are 15 steps:

Download latest OpenSSL package.

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz
```

Unzip

```
tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz
```

Enter folder

```
cd openssl-1.0.2l
```

Config

```
./config --shared
```

Install

```
make && make install
```

That's not the end of the journey, you have to update curl too. Download the latest version of curl.

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.55.1.tar.gz
```

Unzip

```
tar -xzvf curl-7.55.1.tar.gz
```

Enter folder

```
cd curl-7.55.1
```

Set lib path

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/ssl/lib
```

Config

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/curl/ --without-nss --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/
```

Install

```
make && make install
```

Backup a bit

```
mv /usr/bin/curl /usr/bin/curl.bak
```

Link it

```
ln -s /usr/local/curl/bin/curl /usr/bin/curl
```

Finally, check your curl version by

```
curl --version
```

If you did all these steps correctly, it shows

```
curl 7.55.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.55.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2l
```