# Client token not generated in AWS Server for Sandbox account

Tags: zend-framework, braintree

Client token is not generated for sandbox account in Braintree. Previously it was working fine.

When logged into Braintree Sandbox account, it shows the following message in the dashboard

"As part of PCI 3.1 requirements, we've recently deprecated support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1 in the Sandbox. You can find information on how to update your systems here - "

Is this the cause for the issue?

Below is the code we use to generate client token:

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
            Braintree_Configuration::environment($config->payment->braintree->environment);
            Braintree_Configuration::merchantId($config->payment->braintree->merchantId);
            Braintree_Configuration::publicKey($config->payment->braintree->publicKey);
            Braintree_Configuration::privateKey($config->payment->braintree->privateKey);
            $clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
```

We have a project developed in Zend Framework 1.12 version.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

When I use getMessage option in catch block, it doesn't show any error messages. But when I use the TraceAsString I receive the following message:

```
 /home/userName/projects/projectName/vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/Http.php(101): Braintree\Http->_doUrlRequest('POST', 'https://api.san...', '_doRequest('POST', '/merchants/kyfn...', 'post('/merchants/kyfn...', Array) #3 /home/userName/projects/projectName/vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/ClientTokenGateway.php(47): Braintree\ClientTokenGateway->_doGenerate('/client_token', Array) #4 /home/userName/projects/projectName/vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/ClientToken.php(18): Braintree\ClientTokenGateway->generate(Array) #5 /home/userName/projects/projectName/application/util/BaseController.php(1336): Braintree\ClientToken::generate() #6 /home/userName/projects/projectName/application/controllers/OffersController.php(856): BaseController->getClientToken() #7 /home/userName/projects/projectName/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516): OffersController->checkoutAction() #8 /home/userName/projects/projectName/application/util/BaseController.php(780): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('checkoutAction') #9 /home/userName/projects/projectName/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(308): BaseController->dispatch('checkoutAction') #10 /home/userName/projects/projectName/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #11 /home/userName/projects/projectName/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(105): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #12 /home/userName/projects/projectName/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Application.php(384): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() #13 /home/userName/projects/projectName/public/index.php(39): Zend_Application->run() #14 /home/userName/projects/projectName/public/dev-router.php(6): require('/home/userName/pr...') #15 {main}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Do you have any error logs you can add to your question?

Comment: I have added the changes in the question.. Please review it..

Comment: What happens when you call `Braintree_ClientToken::generate();`? Is there an error? Can you log the response and share it?

Comment: Actually I didn't receive any error. When I tried to print the error line it showed SSL error. After I updated the CURL version of PHP the issue got resolved as per the Braintree info. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got fixed after I updated the CURL version of PHP as per the Braintree response.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134473/braintree-php-sdk-curl-exception) for anyone who lands here looking for more details about updating your systems to use TLS 1.2 with Braintree Sandbox.