# i got a ssl certificate error when i want to generate a token for every click checkout on braintree

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, braintree

My code is:

```
require_once 'braintree/Braintree.php';
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('6mh3jxjv5smdpyh3');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('j4hgps5mp4bqtm2m');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('97a526828d7402c09d4d5fdfff197ab5');
$arguments=array();
echo $token = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
```

Token generate for localhost.But in server there will be a error Uncaught exception 'Braintree_Exception_SSLCertificate' .the error on Http.php page

Comment: You should use Braintree from composer or just disable the SSL Check from options. There must be some option for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Braintree PHP SDK cURL exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134473/braintree-php-sdk-curl-exception)

Comment: Thank you. I have solved the problem. Actually it was server problem

Answer (score 0):

I got some communication from BT regarding the deprecation of TLSv < 1.2 for their Sandbox, which would entail an update of one's SDK.

https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update/tree/master/Braintree?utm_campaign=BT_NA_US_MerchantNewsletter_Q4_20161025&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua&elq_cid=5173769